# Is there any extension method which get void returning lambda expression ? 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

For example

```
int[] Array = { 1, 23, 4, 5, 3, 3, 232, 32, };

Array.JustDo(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: I know that I can write my own extension method but i wonder is there already exist one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) which doesn't require you to convert to a List<> first.

```
int[] a = { 1, 23, 4, 5, 3, 3, 232, 32, };
Array.ForEach(a, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: int[] array hasn't that extension method.

Comment: @Freshblood - but the array class does.  You just have to do it like the sample shows.

Comment: @Freshblood: If you look at my code example Array is not the name of the int array it's the name of the Array class.  And yes it works with int arrays as my code demonstrates.  You can compile it and try it.

Comment: @Brian sorry.At a glance i haven't seen that you defined int[] a but i had defined int[] array :) thats why i haven't consider your extension method

Comment: @Freshblood: np, I had to change the name of the variable for that reason :)

Comment: Also, be careful with this.  It works because `Console.Writeline()` has an overload that accepts `int` (and `object`, for that matter).  If you're expecting a `string` there you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Array.ForEach method

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Array.ForEach(array, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

or make your own extension method

```
void Main()
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    array.JustDo(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}

public static class MyExtension
{
    public static void JustDo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ext, Action<T> a)
    {
        foreach(T item in ext)
        {
            a(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int[] array hasn't that extension method but It is nice to know collection has this extension.

Comment: Writing extension method is also not bad.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you *can* use `Array.ForEach`. However, you might like to read [Eric Lippert's thoughts on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).

If you still want it after reading that, there *is* the `Do` method in the `System.Interactive` assembly which is part of [Reactive Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29), as part of `EnumerableEx`. You'd use it like this:

```
int[] array = { 1, 23, 4, 5, 3, 3, 232, 32, };   
array.Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

(I've changed the name of the variable to avoid confusion. It's generally better not to name variables with the same name as a type.)

There's plenty of great stuff to look at in Reactive Extensions...

Comment: @Freshblood: No, it's in the System.Interactive assembly which is part of Reactive Extensions. I think it's still in the System.Linq namespace. I'll edit my post to make this clearer.